# Android java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported class file major version 61

Tags: android, android-studio, build.gradle, gradlew

Hello everyone once I update my android studio to Arctic fox while publishing the artifact(command - ./gradlew assembleRelease artifactoryPublish) I am getting this error. I have written below gradle details please help me out for the same

JDK version: **11**

gradle.properties or gradle version

```
https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.0.2-bin.zip
```

Build tool version

```
 classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.3'
```

Kotlin Version

```
1.5.31
```

Comment: Major version 61 is Java 17 - https://javaalmanac.io/bytecode/versions/. The Java version you are using on the command line is Java 17, not Java 11 - fix that in the command line environment, be it bash, zsh or cmd.  The project setup JDK  (`Build, Execution, Deployment -> Build Tools -> Gradle -> Gradle JDK`) can differ from the command line env JDK. Type `javac -version` to confirm.  Also try running the gradle task directly from the gradle tasks list in the IDE - the will use the Project JDK if you are not successful setting the command line JDK.

Comment: @MarkKeen I am executing that command(./gradlew assembleRelease artifactoryPublish) from the android terminal and after checking java version from android terminal its showing 17 but I can see the project setting its 11 not sure why its talking system java JDK not android one

Comment: please check this:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/73509483/4479395

Comment: @Mark very useful comment and clearly explains what's wrong. Thanks!