# Android Studio Error "Unsupported class file major version 61"

Tags: java, android, android-studio, unsupported-class-version

I moved my Android Studio project from one computer to another computer and now I get this error:

> "Unsupported class file major version 61" .

[image]

How can I fix this?

Comment: For me, I had to upgrade gradle. see https://stackoverflow.com/a/71844064/7429464

Answer (score 43, accepted):

With the help of [@Robert answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70632872/10749567),
I found out that the problem was with JAVA 17 and that the Gradle JDK in use was:
`Android Studio java home version 17.0.1`

I changed it to:
`Android Studio default JDK version 11.0.10`

[image]

Then everything worked like before...

You'll find the Gradle Settings under `File > Project Structure...`
[image]

...or through the Toolbar button: `Project Structure...`
[image]

Then click the `Gradle Settings` link.
[image]

Comment: Strom I am using the JDK version 11.0.15 but still, I couldn't able to download the library and the compiler showed the error  "Unsupported class file major version 61".
is there any specific version I need to use for downloading the library?

Comment: That's because by default, Flutter uses Android Studio's embedded JDK, which in your case is Java 17

Answer (score 14):

**class file major version 61** means that the class file you are trying to load has been compiled by Java 17 or higher and can only by used by Java 17+.

The Android toolchain only supports classes compiled for Java 11 (if the project is properly configured). So there is something wrong with the library you are trying to load.

As you don't give any details in your question what you are trying to do, it is impossible to give you a more detailed answer.

Answer (score 12):

Step 1:

- Change version on 'gradle-wrapper.properties' file

'distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.7-all.zip'
to
'distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.6-all.zip'

Step 2:

- In gradle.properties file remove this line 'org.gradle.java.home'

Step 3:

- In android/build.gradle file:

  ```
  buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.7.21'
    dependencies {
      classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.0'
      classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
  }
  ```

Answer (score 1):

for mac users, please follow this:

download and install java 11 from [here](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/downloads/#java11)

edit your zshrc file with this:

```
export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home)
```

open terminal and execute :

```
cd /Applications/Android\ Studio.app/Contents/jre
ln -s ../jre jdk
ln -s "/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin" jdk
```

Now run `flutter doctor -v`

Answer (score 0):

For those ending up on this thread after upgrading to a newer version of Android Studio, here is the official documentation to fix your issue :
https://docs.flutter.dev/release/breaking-changes/android-java-gradle-migration-guide

You're having this issue because Flutter is, by default, using Android Studio's embedded JDK Version.
Your best solution here is to embrace the new version of the JDK and to upgrade Gradle accordingly