# Could not compile settings file Settings.gradle while creating build in ionic cordova app

Tags: android, cordova, gradle, hybrid-mobile-app

Getting this error from last couple of days could not able to get solution.

using below command to generate android apk using ionic and cordova

```
ionic cordova build android
```

General error during conversion: Unsupported class file major version 61
[You can checkout the error here for better understanding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PRFq3.png)

I am using
Gradle v7.4.2
java v17.0.2

Automated code in **settings.gradle** file is

```
// GENERATED FILE - DO NOT EDIT
apply from: "cdv-gradle-name.gradle"
include ":"
include ":CordovaLib"
include ":app"
```

Comment: Read this, it will help you most likely: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70632741/android-studio-error-unsupported-class-file-major-version-61