# Questions about SHA-1 in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, keystore, sha, app-bundle

good morning all, I've some questions about SHA-1 in flutter I hope to be helpful to all
firstly, I want to know Is SHA-1 unique for each project?

secondly, in my first project in a flutter, I could generate SHA-1 easily but later on I couldn't, I've an error like this this

```
PS D:\hadayek_hof\android> ./gradlew signingReport

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file 'D:\hadayek_hof\android\build.gradle' line: 26

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'android'.
> A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
   > Could not open proj generic class cache for build file 'D:\hadayek_hof\android\app\build.gradle' (C:\Users\sayed\.gradle\caches\6.7\scripts\4itc8kesudlin9k959r0b6kz0).
      > BUG! exception in phase 'semantic analysis' in source unit '_BuildScript_' Unsupported class file major version 62

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 3s
```

actually, I tried all of the answers to this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51845559/11287483) but no one working for except only one solution but it gave me the SHA-1 for my first project
how can I get SHA-1 for each project?

third is SHA-1 related to debug KeyStore and upload KeyStore ? should I remove them each time I want to generate an app bundle for a new flutter project

totally in a few words: how to deal with SHA-1 && debug/upload KeyStore for each new flutter project

Comment: "Unsupported class file major version 62" -> You are using the wrong Java version for compiling (too new).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android Studio Error "Unsupported class file major version 61"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70632741/android-studio-error-unsupported-class-file-major-version-61)

Comment: no, it doesn't work for me. and i want to get answers for my questions

Answer (score 1):

Every app has different SHA key you need to update it for each project that you do. Secondly In this error first you need to clearly see the error mentioned in build.gradle file as it is related to it. So you can run --stackrace,--info or --debug for more detailed error.