# Android studio how to fix "Unsupported class file major version 64"

Tags: java, android, android-studio, unsupported-class-version

Whenever I try to build or clean the project or try again. I am getting the following error

`Unsupported class file major version 64`

I am stuck to this problem and unable to find the solution

**gradle-wrapper.properties**

```
#Wed Oct 21 11:43:07 PKT 2020
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.0-all.zip
```

**build.gradle**

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    google()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.1.3'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
   }
 }

 allprojects {
   repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    google()
 }
}

 tasks.register('clean', Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**build.gradle(:app)**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 33
buildToolsVersion '28.0.2'

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.thumbsol.accuratemobileassetsmanagament"
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 33
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner 'androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner'
    vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}

lintOptions {
    checkReleaseBuilds false
}
}

dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
androidTestImplementation('androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.10.0'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.9.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.9.0'
implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:10.2.3'
implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
implementation 'androidx.vectordrawable:vectordrawable:1.1.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
implementation 'com.toptoche.searchablespinner:searchablespinnerlibrary:1.3.1'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:10.2.3'
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.9.1'
implementation 'com.github.luongvo:GmailBackground:2.0.2'
}
```

**Project Structure**

[image]

I have also tried this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70641605/6854117) but unable to resolve the problem

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Usually this is caused by a library that was compiled for a Java version which is too new. In your case Java 20 (class file version 64). You need to identify the class or library which causes the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's likely that your build process is using different JDKs to build libraries and your app. This discrepancy can cause the issue you're encountering.

To solve the problem in the simplest way, I suggest using only one JDK version - specifically, the one defined in your **JAVA_HOME** environment variable. Delete the others to avoid any conflicts.

Open your terminal and type:

```
java --version
```

You might see an output like this:

> openjdk 17.0.9 2023-10-17 OpenJDK Runtime Environment Temurin-17.0.9+9
> (build 17.0.9+9) OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Temurin-17.0.9+9 (build
> 17.0.9+9, mixed mode)

Now, check the path to your JDK files:

```
echo $JAVA_HOME
```

An example output on macOS could be:

> /Users/lucasmiranda/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-17.0.9+9/Contents/Home

Navigate to the *JavaVirtualMachines* folder.

Delete the other JDK versions and keep only the one used by your **JAVA_HOME**.

If you encounter an issue with Android Studio trying to use a different JDK, configure it to point to your default JDK version.